# os.path.expanduser not returning "C:\Users\<username>\" directory

Tags: python, directory, windows-10, desktop, os.path

I'm trying to find my desktop directory using:

```
os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\')
```

But when I print() this, I get "C:\home\Desktop" as directory path, instead of the "C:\Users\[username]\Desktop". I recently did the windows 7 to windows 10 update, and don't recall this being an issue before when I had windows 7.

I tried researching this but not getting very far... Has this happened to anyone?  Any help/reference is appreciated.

Comment: If you type `os.listdir(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\'))`, does it show you the right things?

Comment: Looking at `ntpath.py`, `expanduser` looks at `HOME`, `USERPROFILE`, `HOMEPATH` and `HOMEDRIVE`. What are those values on your system? Better yet, use pdb to step through the code and see what is assembled.   ... then let us know!

Comment: if I type os.listdir(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\')), it only lists the one folder I have in the "C:\home\Desktop".